# How to loop thorugh mongoDB with a promise and a forEach loop? I want to populate an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, foreach, promise

I am trying to loop through elements in my MongoDB database and save the values to an Array.
However, after hours of struggling I can't get it done.

Here's my code:

```
//shopController.js

const Product = require('../models/product');
const User = require('../models/user');


exports.getCart = (req, res, next) => {
    const productIds = [];
    const productsArr = [];
    let userData = null;

    User.findById(req.user._id)
        .then(user => {
            userData = user;
            userData.cart.items.map(prodId => {
                productIds.push(prodId.productId);
            }) 
            console.log(productIds); // [ 5dc1b6ace13a97588620d6c6, 5dc1b6ace13a97588620d6c6 ]
            return productIds;
        })
        .then(prodIds => {
            prodIds.forEach(prodId => {
                Product.findById(prodId)
                    .then(product => {
                        productsArr.push(product);
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err))
            })
            console.log(productsArr); // []
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            const error = new Error(err);
            error.httpStatusCode = 500;
            return next(error);
        });
}
```

Don't mind the first output, it's intended to display the same ID twice.
The result when I am logging the `productsArr[]` is always an empty Array, except i place the `console.log(productsArr);` **inside** the `forEach()` loop, which i don't want because it gets logged too often and I can't render an EJS page like this.

The render function would look like this:

```
res.render('shop/cart', {
                path: '/cart',
                docTitle: 'Cart',
                products: productsArr,
                userData: userData
            });
```

I can't get the `products` into the `productsArr[]`, as soon as i try to access the `productsArr[]` **outside** of the forEach() loop I got an empty Array, so I don't know how to go about this.

Do you have any advice?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to render it after the Promises all resolve using `Promise.prototype.all`, there's no other way to get the populated `productsArr` array.

Try this:

```js
//shopController.js

const Product = require('../models/product');
const User = require('../models/user');


exports.getCart = (req, res, next) => {
    const productIds = [];
//    const productsArr = []; not needed anymore
    let userData = null;

    User.findById(req.user._id)
        .then(user => {
            userData = user;
            userData.cart.items.map(prodId => {
                productIds.push(prodId.productId);
            })
            console.log(productIds); // [ 5dc1b6ace13a97588620d6c6, 5dc1b6ace13a97588620d6c6 ]
            return productIds;
        })
        .then(prodIds => {
            Promise.all(prodIds.map(prodId =>
                Product.findById(prodId)
            ).then(productsArr => {
                res.render('shop/cart', {
                    path: '/cart',
                    docTitle: 'Cart',
                    products: productArr,
                    userData: userData
                });
                console.log(productsArr); // [ ... products ... ]
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            const error = new Error(err);
            error.httpStatusCode = 500;
            return next(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that this is working. It doesn't insert the data into the array, but this is not a big deal, this is solving my main problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are not waiting for your product promises to be finished, to display your data. You can use the `Promise.all([])` function to wait for multiple promises at once.

```
 .then(prodIds => {
        Promise.all(prodIds.map(prodId => {
                return Product.findById(prodId)
                    .then(product => {
                        productsArr.push(product);
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err))
            })).then(() => {
                console.log(
        })
```

Here we are mapping every product ids to a promise (`Product.findById`) and then passing all of them into the `Promise.all()` function, which takes an array.
We then wait for all the promise to be resolve, and call the `then` function. 
This way, you are sure all of your promise are finished before printing your data.

Comment: I did not downvote I am still trying to get it to work with these answers! Thank you for your help I am on it! I will let you know if it worked!

Comment: Don't worry, i know you didn't. I just hope the person who did would give me feedback. @MarioHess

Comment: This worked like a charm! I have to read about Promise.all(). Thank you very much for taking your time!

Comment: @MarioHess I'm glad I could help !